# PostgreSQL: Sub-select inside insert

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, subquery

I have a table called `map_tags`:

```
map_id | map_license | map_desc
```

And another table (`widgets`) whose records contains a foreign key reference (1 to 1) to a `map_tags` record:

```
widget_id | map_id | widget_name
```

Given the constraint that all `map_license`s are unique (however are not set up as keys on `map_tags`), then if I have a `map_license` and a `widget_name`, I'd like to perform an insert on `widgets` all inside of the same SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO
    widgets w
(
    map_id,
    widget_name
)
VALUES (
    (
        SELECT
            mt.map_id
        FROM
            map_tags mt
        WHERE
            // This should work and return a single record because map_license is unique
            mt.map_license = '12345'
    ),
    'Bupo'
)
```

I *believe* I'm on the right track but know right off the bat that this is incorrect SQL for Postgres. Does anybody know the proper way to achieve such a single query?

Comment: Have never done it with PostgreSQL, but shouldn't it look like `INSERT INTO widgets SELECT NULL, map_id, 'Bupo' FROM map_tags WHERE map_license = '12345'`?

Comment: Thanks @raina77ow (+1) - I'm not sure if that's what it should be. The `SELECT` statement in lieu of the `(...) VALUES(...)` syntax is definitely throwing me off though. Would you mind explaining to me how that should work? Thanks again!

Comment: Well, I just use it like [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) in MySQL... The reason, I suppose, is that you have to build the whole set of data that would be inserted - and VALUES ((SELECT smth), 'smth_else') just doesn't do it. )

Comment: You don't actually need to use values according to this syntax: INSERT INTO table2
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO widgets
(
    map_id,
    widget_name
)
SELECT
    mt.map_id, 'Bupo'
FROM
    map_tags mt
WHERE
    mt.map_license = '12345'
```

Comment: This is a super useful syntax when the table you want to insert into has a SERIAL PK or similar

Answer (score 75):

Use the `INSERT INTO SELECT` variant, including whatever constants right into the `SELECT` statement.

The PostgreSQL `INSERT` syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO table [ ( column [, ...] ) ]
 { DEFAULT VALUES | VALUES ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) [, ...] | query }
 [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
```

Take note of the **query** option at the end of the second line above.

Here is an example for you.

```
INSERT INTO 
    widgets
    (
        map_id,
        widget_name
    )
SELECT 
   mt.map_id,
   'Bupo'
FROM
    map_tags mt
WHERE
    mt.map_license = '12345'
```

Comment: Why has the other almost identical but less complete and one minute later answer been voted up more and accepted?

Comment: Because stack exchange was becoming a much too powerful tool. So they decided to leave it pretty broken.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Answer:**
You don't have "**a single record**" you have a "**set with 1 record**"
If this were javascript: You have an "array with 1 value" not "1 value".

**In your example**, one record may be returned in the sub-query,
but you are still trying to unpack an "array" of records into separate
actual parameters into a place that takes only 1 parameter.

It took me a few hours to wrap my head around the "why not".
As I was trying to do something very similiar:

Here are my notes:

```
tb_table01: (no records)
+---+---+---+
| a | b | c | << column names
+---+---+---+

tb_table02:
+---+---+---+
| a | b | c | << column names
+---+---+---+
|'d'|'d'|'d'| << record #1
+---+---+---+
|'e'|'e'|'e'| << record #2
+---+---+---+
|'f'|'f'|'f'| << record #3
+---+---+---+

--This statement will fail:
INSERT into tb_table01
    ( a, b, c )
VALUES
    (  'record_1.a', 'record_1.b', 'record_1.c' ),
    (  'record_2.a', 'record_2.b', 'record_2.c' ),

    -- This sub query has multiple
    -- rows returned. And they are NOT
    -- automatically unpacked like in 
    -- javascript were you can send an
    -- array to a variadic function.
    (
        SELECT a,b,c from tb_table02
    ) 
    ;
```

Basically, **don't** think of "**VALUES**" as a **variadic**
function that can unpack an array of records. There is
no argument unpacking here like you would have in a javascript
function. Such as:

```
function takeValues( ...values ){ 
    values.forEach((v)=>{ console.log( v ) });
};

var records = [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] ];
takeValues( records );

//:RESULT:
//: console.log #1 : [1,2,3]
//: console.log #2 : [4,5,7]
//: console.log #3 : [7,8,9]
```

**Back to your SQL question:**

The reality of this functionality not existing does not change
just because your sub-selection contains only one result. It is
a "**set with one record**" not "**a single record**".